# Determine if there is a character in a string that occur exactly K times

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What I do is to do a nested loop that achieves `O(n^2)` time. My question is if there is a better solution that can reduce the time complexity?

Comment: An abstract approach: reduce the string to a histogram. Scan the histogram for entries where the frequency is 3. The keys are the characters which occur exactly three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in `O(n)`. You just have a hash of all characters (even can be an array). When you iterate over your string you increment the number of the character that you have found.

Then at the end you iterate over your hash and output all the keys, whose values is equal to `k`.

and a quick couple of lines in python

```
def func(s, k):
    from collections import Counter
    h = Counter(s)
    return [i for i in h if h[i] == k]
```

this will return you all the characters that occur `k` times in the string `s`.

Comment: Thank you Salvador. But if I keep a hashtable, for every iteration I need to check if the elements already exists, so every iteration there is a O(logN) time and the total running time is O(NlogN), am I right?

Comment: @Zongyang please read time complexity of basic data structures, your search in hash is `O(1)`.